# Filter new line from array of email strings

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, email, nsarray

I'm trying to send emails to a list that I get from a server which is an array of emails whose output is in this format

```
(
    "john@gmail.com\n",
    "katebell@gmail.com\n"
     "\nakhil@gmail.com",
     "mary@gmail.com",
     "timcorb\n@gmail.com
)
```

Now as you can see some emails have newline characters in between and those emails doesnt get sent. I'm trying to find an efficient way to filter out those newlines, my current approach is  to loop through all emails and check for newline in each email and if newline exist replace it with a null string. Is there a better way to do this or should I just stick with that? Also Will my current approach cause any issues in any other scenarios?

Comment: your current approach is good for replacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can  try using `NSRegularExpression` like this below :-

```
    NSArray *array=@[@"john@gmail.com\n",@"katebell@gmail.com\n",@"\nakhil@gmail.com",@"mary@gmail.com",@"timcorb\n@gmail.com"];
    NSString *string =[array componentsJoinedByString: @","];
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",modifiedString);
```

Output:-

```
john@gmail.com,katebell@gmail.com,akhil@gmail.com,mary@gmail.com,timcorb@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
NSString *fileName = @"\ntest\n";  
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

eg.

```
   NSString * str = @"timcorb\n@gmail.com";
   str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
   NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

it will Log `2014-01-10 01:01:00.256 demo[26220] timcorb@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for replacing characters in a string.

```
    NSString *email = @"\nakhi\nl@gmail.com";

    NSString *actualEmail = [email stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* emailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int _index = 0; _index < [yourArray count]; _index++) {
  [emailArray addobject:[[yourArray objectAtIndex:_index]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];
}
```

This will give you your email array